# dayClick function is not working after select function in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Im using both function together. here is my code:-

```
select: function (start, end, allDay) { 
  var selectedStartTime = start.format('HH:mm');
  ... 
},

dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){ 
 popupopen = 1;
},
```

When i select a timeslot, dayClick function fire first and then select function. This is ok. But, when select function fires first(multiple timeslots are selected) dayClick function is stop working. How to fix this?

Comment: can you share your code for better understanding

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: No, not getting any error.

Comment: Here is my code:-   select:function (start, end, allDay){alert(select function is clicked!);
    var selectedStartTime = start.format('HH:mm'); 
    var selectedEndTime = end.format('HH:mm'); 
    },
    
 dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){alert(dayClick function is clicked!);
    popupopen = 1;
    var clickedTime = date.format('HH:mm');
    var endTimeAfterclickedTime = date.add(15, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');
    ... And other code comes here
   
 },